# MySQL Point in Time Recovery For Just a Single Schema?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, logs

Is it possible to simply restore a single schema and bring it to a point in time (Say three hours ago) without bringing the entire database back?

I can think of a lengthy method of backing up each schema individually at present time, bringing the database back three hours and restoring all other schemas (except for the one you want to roll back) back to present time.

Is there any other method? Or am I not understanding binary logs correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the SQL from a specific schema with the

Use [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) utility against all binary logs that have the data and time ranges. You will have to name the database you are extracting:

- [start-datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_start-datetime)
- [stop-datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_stop-datetime)
- [database (-d)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_database)

For example, suppose you have the following scenario

- You have these binary logs
- mysql-bin.000019
- mysql-bin.000020
- mysql-bin.000021
- mysql-bin.000022
- Binary Logs span from `2013-01-30 09:30:00` to `2013-02-04 12:00:00`
- You have a full backup from `2013-02-03 00:00:00` (`mysqldata-20130203.sql`)
- You want to restore MyProdDB from 02/03/13 at 2:45 PM `2013-02-03 14:45:00`

#STEP 01) Get all DB Changes from the Binary Logs

```
DB=MyProdDB
BEG_DT="2013-02-03 00:00:00"
END_DT="2013-02-03 14:45:00"
BINLOGS="mysql-bin.000019 mysql-bin.000020 mysql-bin.000021 mysql-bin.000022"
mysqlbinlog -d ${DB} --start-datetime="${BEG_DT}" --stop-datetime="${END_DT}" ${BINLOGS} > mysqldata-delta.sql
```

#STEP 02) Load Data into Staging Database called `MyProdDBStaging`

```
mysql -u... -p... -DMyProdDBStaging < mysqldata-20130203.sql
```

#STEP 03) Load Delta into Staging Database called `MyProdDBStaging`

```
mysql -u... -p... -DMyProdDBStaging < mysqldata-delta.sql
```

Now, the target database will be the point and time instance for `MyProdDB` at 2:45 PM on Feb 3, 2013.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Rolando, you're a MySQL machine :)

Comment: Awesome! You're the man. Time to go practice this.

Comment: This implemented for cPanel would be a wonderful solution!

Comment: Is there a way to perform this without using a staging database?
By just selecting the bin-logs related to the MyProdDB and just apply those ones...

Comment: @DavideCarta what you are asking for is already covered in STEP 01. The `-d` option of mysqlbinlog script selects binlogs events from the `MyProdDB` only.

Comment: As a big precaution, I say staging database first so you can check the validity of the restore. If you are satisfied with the restore's content, you can repeat the steps on the Prod Server.